# Convert a list of dictionaries within a dataframe to a list of strings - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

No amount of googling seems to make this any simpler for me and most of the results I get are about different conversions, so here goes.

Given a dataframe column with values like

[{'id': 5, 'value': 'string1'},{'id': 3, 'value': 'string3'},{'id': 35, 'value': 'string2'}]

How do I convert this to a list of stings such as

['string1','string2','string3']

I attempted to use two for loops such as,

```
for x in df:
    for y in x:
       y = y['value']
```

And this seems to work when i add in a print(y) after the operation, but the change doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: Use `df['value'].tolist()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append values to lists:

```
L = []
for x in df['col']:
    L1 = []
    for y in x:
       L1.append(y['value'])
    L.append(L1)

df['new'] = L
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [[y['value'] for y in x] for x in df['col']]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[{'id': 5, 'value': 'string1'},{'id': 3, 'value': 'string3'},{'id': 35, 'value': 'string2'}],
                          [{'id': 5, 'value': 'string1'},{'id': 3, 'value': 'string3'}]]})

df['new'] = [[y['value'] for y in x] for x in df['col']]
print (df)

                                                 col  \
0  [{'id': 5, 'value': 'string1'}, {'id': 3, 'val...   
1  [{'id': 5, 'value': 'string1'}, {'id': 3, 'val...   

                           new  
0  [string1, string3, string2]  
1           [string1, string3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tolist` function of **`pandas DataFrame`**

```
df['value'].tolist()
```

This will give you the result you expect for

```
['string1', 'string3', 'string2']
```